# subtract two timestamps and difference in hhmmss

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns started at and ended at,
1.I want to find the time difference between two columns in hhmmss format in another column as ride_length.
2. I want to find the avg of ride_length for all the rows in a column.

Below are the columns

```
started_at                           ended_at                       
2020-12-18 10:06:31 UTC            2020-12-18 10:16:34 UTC
2020-12-03 07:46:32 UTC            2020-12-03 08:17:19 UTC
```

```
select * from
  (select a.*, TIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIFFERENCE))AS HHMMSS 
   from 
   (SELECT DATE_DIFF(started_at, ended_at, SECOND) AS difference 
    FROM
    avid-winter-405805.bikesharingdata.jan
  ) a
) b;
```

Expected output

```
ride_length        avg(ride_length)
12:30:40            00:02:03
02:02:30            00:32:10
```

Comment: mysql and google-bigquery syntax differs. Select only one DBMS and remove unrelated tag.

Comment: If you want to find "the avg of ride_length for all the rows in a column" then that's a single value - so how have you managed to generate two values in your expected output?

Comment: The time difference between the given example data is 00:10:03 and 00:30:47. Your expected output has complete different values. Your task is unclear.